# looking for a loss function sensitive to edges for medical image quality enhuncement

Tags: pytorch, loss-function, medical-imaging

For an image-to-image translation task in which I want to generate high-quality images from low-quality images ( MRI Images), I need a loss function to highlight the edges and generate images with sharper edges.
Do you have any recommendation for selecting the desired loss function between Pytorch's loss function??

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#loss-functions

I really appreciate it if anyone can even provide me the code of any predefined loss function for this task.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using `MSE` loss function at the moment? This loss function indeed tends to prefer "smoother" outputs rather than sharp edges.

For image generation tasks, consider using [perceptual loss](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/image/learned_perceptual_image_patch_similarity.html) that better correlates with human perception of image quality.

For more details on this loss function see
*R. Zhang, P. Isola, A. A. Efros, E. Shechtman, O. Wang* [**The Unreasonable effectiveness of Deep Features as a Perceptual Metric**](https://richzhang.github.io/PerceptualSimilarity/) (CVPR 2018).